# Grep pattern with Multiple lines with AND operation

Tags: regex, awk, grep, multiline

How can I determine a pattern exists over multiple lines with grep? below is a multiline pattern I need to check is present in the file

> ```
>  Status:    True
>  Type:   Master
> ```

I tried the below command but it checks multiple strings on a single line but fails for strings pattern match on multiple lines

```
  if cat file.txt  | grep -P '^(?=.*Status:.*True)(?=.*Type:.*Master)'; then echo "Present"; else echo "NOT FOUND"; fi
```

file.txt

> ```
> Interface:                      vlan
> Status:                         True
> Type:                           Master
> ID:                             104
> ```

Comment: Are the lines always in that order? Can there ever be any other lines? You use `.*`  implying there can be 'anything' after the colon and before the target word, what about after the word? And should you really be searching for just whitespace there? (You really need to describe what can and can not be in this file in detail, don't assume anything is irrelevant.)

Comment: Assuming the lines are always in order. The file is fixed output returned from a command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `gnu-grep` you can do this:

```sh
grep -zoP '(?m)^\s*Status:\s+True\s+Type:\s+Master\s*' file

Status:                         True
Type:                           Master
```

**Explanation:**

- `P`: Enabled PCRE regex mode
- `-z`: Reads multiline input
- `-o`: Prints only matched data
- `(?m)` Enables MULTILINE mode so that we can use `^` before each line
- `^`: Start a line

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` program. Written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
awk -v RS='(^|\n)Status:[[:space:]]+True\nType:[[:space:]]+Master' '
RT{
  sub(/^\n/,"",RT)
  print RT
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be setting `RS`(Record separator of `awk`) as regex `(^|\n)Status:[[:space:]]+True\nType:[[:space:]]+Master`(explained below) and in main program checking if `RT` is NOT NULL then remove new line(starting one) in `RT` with NULL and print value of `RT` to get expected output shown by OP.

Answer (score 1):

I did it as follows:

```
grep -A 1 "^.*Status:.*True" test.txt | grep -B 1 "^Type:.*Master"
```

The `-A x` means "also show the `x` lines **A**fter the found one.
The `-B y` means "also show the `y` lines **B**efore the found one.

So: show the "Status" line together with the next one (the "Type" one), and then show the "Type" line together with the previous one (the "Status" one).

Answer (score 0):

You could also keep track of the previous line setting in every line at the end `prev = $0` and use a pattern to match the previous and the current line.

```
awk  '
prev ~ /^[[:space:]]*Status:[[:space:]]*True$/ && $0 ~ /^[[:space:]]*Type:[[:space:]]*Master$/{
    printf "%s\n%s", prev, $0
}
{prev = $0}
' file.txt
```

Output

```
Status:                         True
Type:                           Master
```